# Rotation of array of vectors using pyquaternion

Tags: python, data-science, quaternions

I have a numpy ndarray of shape (112414,3). i want to rotate these 112414 vectors around same axis and angle using pyquaternion. is there a way to get all rotated vectors at once instead of applying a loop of size 112414?

```
rotation_axis=np.random.uniform(size=3)
my_quaternion = Quaternion(axis=rotation_axis,degrees=np.random.uniform(low=0,high=361))

for i in np.arange(len(linear_arr)):

    x=my_quaternion.rotate(Quaternion(vector=linear_arr[i])).vector
```

i want to remove this loop. i want to give complete linear_arr which is ndarray of shape (112414,3) and get an array of rotated vectors of same shape. because this code above is computationally expensive and taking too much time on my machine

Comment: Compute the rotation matrix from your quaternion and then just multiply it with `linear_arr`?

Answer (score 0):

better to write your own code to do matrix rotation as matrix multiplication